# Golang Interpret gdb SIGILL, Illegal Instruction

Tags: go, gdb, mips, embedded-linux, go-ethereum

I've written a small go program to be run on a MIPS 32-bit router. I'm able to get a basic hello world program running on the router using the go build toolchain.

```
env GOOS=linux GOARCH=mips GOMIPS=softfloat go build -a
```

The program I'm trying to compile uses a the go-ethereum library and throws the following error when I try build

```
go build github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto/secp256k1: build constraints exclude all Go files in ~/go/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto/secp256k1
```

I found the go cross-compilation tool xgo and have been successful in building a binary with that tool (https://github.com/karalabe/xgo). When I try to run the binary though I get the following 'Program terminated with signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction'. I was able to get a core dump from the file but I don't have much experience with GDB.

```
Program terminated with signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
#0  0x008274a8 in __sigsetjmp_aux ()
```

Running layout asm I get the following:

```
    0x8274a4 <__sigsetjmp_aux+4>    addiu  gp,gp,-19312                                                                                                                          │
  >│0x8274a8 <__sigsetjmp_aux+8>    sdc1   $f20,56(a0)                                                                                                                           │
   │0x8274ac <__sigsetjmp_aux+12>   sdc1   $f22,64(a0)
```

I'm unsure how to interpret this any help would be much appreciated.

Here it he output of  cat /proc/cpuinfo :

```
system type     : Qualcomm Atheros QCA9533 ver 2 rev 0
machine         : GL.iNet GL-AR750
processor       : 0
cpu model       : MIPS 24Kc V7.4
BogoMIPS        : 432.53
wait instruction    : yes
microsecond timers  : yes
tlb_entries     : 16
extra interrupt vector  : yes
hardware watchpoint : yes, count: 4, address/irw mask: [0x0ffc, 0x0ffc, 0x0ffb, 0x0ffb]
isa         : mips1 mips2 mips32r1 mips32r2
ASEs implemented    : mips16
shadow register sets    : 1
kscratch registers  : 0
package         : 0
core            : 0
VCED exceptions     : not available
VCEI exceptions     : not available
```

and the output of the file util on the binary:

```
ELF 32-bit MSB executable, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1, statically linked, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=83c74323a279af9cba50869671ef03d5ad497db8, not stripped
```

I've spent quite a lot of time trying to get this program to run, even forking the xgo tool so it can accept the softfloat parameter. Any help or direction on this problem would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm unsure how to interpret this

Google for "MIPS sdc1" shows that this is a floating-point "Store Doubleword from Coprocessor-1" instruction.

A guess: your embedded system doesn't have a floating-point co-processor?

You would likely need to add `-msoft-float` to your `xgo` command and rebuild.

**Update:**

> it is crashing on the same `sdc1` call, the registers are the same `$f20,56(a0)`.

Yes, but is in the *same* function (`__sigsetjmp_aux`), or in some different one?

> Here is the call I'm building with xgo: `xgo --go=1.12 --targets=linux/mips --ldflags '-extldflags "-static -msoft-float"' ~/path/to/project`

It looks like the routine `__sigsetjmp_aux` is coming from GLIBC, which is *not* built by `xgo`.

And the version of GLIBC you are using was built without `-msoft-float`, so you are still linking in the code that expects hardware floating point, that your system lacks.

Step 1: verify where `__sigsetjmp_aux` is coming from. To do so, you need to pass `-y __sigsetjmp_aux` to the linker. Maybe `--ldflags '-extldflags "-static -msoft-float -Wl,-y,__sigsetjmp_aux"'` will do that.

You should see something similar to this:

```
gcc t.o -Wl,-y,setjmp -static
t.o: reference to setjmp
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a(bsd-setjmp.o): definition of setjmp
```

Assuming your definition of `__sigsetjmp_aux` does come from `libc.a`, you'll need to rebuild it with `-msoft-float` in `CFLAGS`.

Note: passing `-msoft-float` to the linker is wrong and will have no effect -- it's a *compiler* flag.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I haven't been able to find any documentation on 'msoft-float' with regards to xgo. Would I pass it in ldflags ? Here is my build command "xgo  --targets=linux/mips   --ldflags '-extldflags "-static"'  ./path/to/project" . Thanks!

Comment: I've added the -msoft-float to the ldflags and I'm running into a similar issue. Is there somewhere I could be missing ?

Comment: @MattLock "running into similar issue" -- *how* similar? Is the crash now in a different routine? Is that different routine coming from a library? Is that library *also* built with `-msoft-float` ?

Comment: it is crashing on the same sdc1 call, the registers are the same $f20,56(a0). Here is the call I'm building with xgo: xgo  --go=1.12 --targets=linux/mips --ldflags '-extldflags "-static -msoft-float"' ~/path/to/project 

Thank you!

Comment: T Your suspicions were correct, the call came from libc.a: 
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/mips-linux-gnu/5/../../../../mips-linux-gnu/lib/../lib/libc.a(setjmp_aux.o): definition of __sigsetjmp_aux

I've gotten further in the process, I believe now that I'm passing CFLAGS. Do I need to pass the -msoft-float to CGO_FLAGS as well ?

passing the cgo flags: /usr/mips-linux-gnu/include/gnu/stubs.h:8:33: fatal error: gnu/stubs-o32_soft.h: No such file or directory. 

Passing libc6-dev_2.28-10_mips.deb as a deps argument to xgo still throws that error as well. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MattLock I am afraid I don't know much about `xgo`. You should probably accept this answer (the original problem is well understood) and ask a different one: "how to do I build a small Go program for MIPS with no hardware FP?". I am also unclear on whether you've succeeded in rebuilding GLIBC, or found an existing soft-float build. That is *required* before you can make any further progress.

Comment: For some more context, I've modified the xgo build.sh (https://github.com/karalabe/xgo/blob/master/docker/base/build.sh) script to include the following tags on line 414 + 415:

CC=mips-linux-gnu-gcc-5 CXX=mips-linux-gnu-g++-5 GOOS=linux GOARCH=mips GOMIPS=softfloat CGO_ENABLED=1 CFLAGS="-msoft-float"

I've added GOMIPS=softfloat (has been there since I posted this) and most recently the CFLAGS parameter.

Edit: I didn't see your follow up, thank you for all your help. I'll post another question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193355/discussion-between-mattlock-and-employed-russian).